# 404 error when writing to a Shopify asset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I've been trying to upload an asset using the shopify_api gem. I made sure I have the appropriate OAuth2 scope (write_themes), and I have no problem reading and even destroying them. The problem is that I get a 404 error when attempting to create or update an asset.

Here's the request the gem is creating:

```
PUT: /admin/themes/3650318/assets.json [{"Content-Type"=>"application/json", "User-Agent"=>"ShopifyAPI/3.0.3 ActiveResource/4.0.0.beta1 Ruby/2.0.0", "X-Shopify-Access-Token"=>"ommitted"}] ({"key":"templates/index.liquid","attachment":"base64 attachment omitted"})
```

For reference, here is the code I've used to make the request (wrapped in a `ShopifyAPI::Session`, of course):

```
ShopifyAPI::Asset.create(key: 'snippets/test.liquid', attachment: some_base64_data, theme_id: 3650318)
```

Or:

```
asset = ShopifyAPI::Asset.new(key: 'snippets/test.liquid', attachment: baset64_data, theme_id: 3650318)
asset.save
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did my response answer your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me...

**To upload to the published theme (no theme id is given)**

```
a = ShopifyAPI::Asset.new
a.key = "assets/google.png"
a.src = "https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png"
a.save
```

**or**

```
ShopifyAPI::Asset.create(key: 'assets/google.png', src: "https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png")
```

**To upload to a specific theme**

```
a = ShopifyAPI::Asset.new
a.key = "assets/google.png"
a.src = "https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png"
a.prefix_options[:theme_id] = "6731537"
a.save
```

**or**

```
ShopifyAPI::Asset.create(key: 'assets/google.png', src: "https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png", theme_id: 6731537)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems quite late for the reply but i am answering this so that it will help other developers facing similar issue.

If you have setup shopify_app gem then you can access the asset API on rails by

```
#This will access the asset of live theme
@assets   = ShopifyAPI::Asset.find(:all)
#or if you want to access the asset of particular theme. 
@assets   = ShopifyAPI::Asset.find(:all, params: {"theme_id": themeid})
```

You can find the detail explanation  [here](http://www.navinbista.com/shopify-asset-api/)